# .push() an Object into an Array updates other similar objects in the Array

Tags: angular, typescript

Quite a strange problem:

In my DOM I generate a list that is clickable. On click a function is called with the clicked object as an argument and this said object is then attributed an ID and pushed into an array. Problem is that all similar objects get their IDs and any other value updated too. Meaning that if I click on Object1 two times, both objects in the array will get updated.

DOM:

```html
<div class="col-3" *ngFor="let product of consolidatedProducts" (click)="selectProduct(product)">
  <div class="productSearchCard">
    <div class="name">
      {{product.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      {{product.price}} {{product.currency}} 
      <span *ngIf="product.unit">
        {{product.unit.short}}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      {{product.description}}
    </div>                                    
  </div>
</div>
```

Component

```js
public selectProduct(product: any) {
  const id = new Date().getTime();
  product.id = id;
  this.selectedProducts.push({
    id,
    component: product
  });
}
```

After the push happens, all object in the array have the same ID in the product even if the id is different in the object id. See output below:

```
[
  0: {
    component: {
      id: 1573220848440
      name: "Set of sticker"
      price: "9"
      quantity: "1"
      sub-category: "Sticker"
      unit: {long: "piece", short: "p."}
    },
    id: 1573220848274
  },
  1: {
    component: {
      id: 1573220848440
      name: "Set of sticker Swiss Realty"
      price: "9"
      quantity: "1"
      sub-category: "Sticker"
      unit: {long: "piece", short: "p."}
    },
    id: 1573220848440
  }
]
```

Replicated here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1bhaqn

Comment: Can you please share the output ?

Comment: You need to make sure that all of your "product" are not in fact the same object in the list multiple times (and you do not show any of the relevant code for that).

Comment: I do assign a new ID to the product object in the component, so the object should be different; I added my output below. As you can see the second object with id `1573220848440` updates also the object.component of id `1573220848274`

Comment: And just to be clear I am talking about pushing two times the exact same Object to the array.

Comment: Please provide a working stackblitz

Comment: I replicated on the stackblits link in the question at the end

Comment: It has nothing to di with `push` and everything to do with `product.id = id;`

Comment: When you call `selectProduct(product)` on click you're always referencing the same object. You need to make a deep copy of the objecte before changing the values.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Is it possible to answer the question down below with a working fix (or at least a rough draft) so I can close it with something that can hopefully help others in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're always referencing the same object in memory when you run `selectProduct(product)`.  You need to make a deep copy of the object before assigning the new values to it, then push the new object to the array.

```
public selectProduct(product: any) {
    // MAKE DEEP COPY OF OBJECT (THERE ARE OTHER WAYS TO DO THIS ALSO)
    const newProduct = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product));
    const id = new Date().getTime();
    newProduct.id = id;
    this.selectedProducts.push({
      id,
      component: newProduct
    });
    console.log(this.selectedProducts);
  }
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjxor4

Answer (score 3):

If you can use spread operators I'd suggest doing something like this to make a copy fo object and push it as new

```
  public selectProduct(product: any) {
    const id = new Date().getTime();
    const newProduct = {
      ...product,
      id
    }
    this.selectedProducts.push({
      id,
      component: newProduct
    });
    console.log(this.selectedProducts);
  }
```